# Error creating bean with name 'redisMessageListenerContainer' : Container already initialized

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

I was trying to upgrade the Spring Boot version of my project which was earlier running on version `2.4.13`, to version `3.1.1`. I have used Redis as a pub/sub in my project and the current version for the `spring-data-redis` is `3.1.1`. After running the application, I got the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisMessageListenerContainer' defined in class path resource [com/XXX/XXX/XX/XXXXXX/config/redis/RedisPubSubConfiguration.class]: Container already initialized
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:941)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at XXX.xxx.xxxx.Application.main(Application.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container already initialized
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer.afterPropertiesSet(RedisMessageListenerContainer.java:171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1816)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
```

I can see the `afterPropertiesSet` method is changed in the current version. I even tried the lower versions like `2.7.4` and `2.7.5` but got the same error.

Can anybody let me know what I am missing or navigate to the correct resource which I can refer to for the migration?